# Tengo Problemas con android estudio al ingresar unas variables y demas

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, webservice

hola amigos que tal me podrian decir por que me marca error en estas lineas de codigo mi android studio, las lineas de codigo que aparecen en negrita o con doble asterisco son mis errores, alguien que me ayude porfavor es urgente

```
package com.example.danhermes.reportestransportepublico;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class reportes extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText nombre, reporte;
Button agregar;
**HttpClient** cliente;
**HttpPost** post;
List<**NameValuePair**> lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reportes);

    nombre = (EditText)(super.findViewById(R.id.etnombre));
    reporte = (EditText)(super.findViewById(R.id.etreporte));

    agregar = (Button)(super.findViewById(R.id.btnagregar));

    agregar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(nombre.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(reportes.this, "Ingresa Un Nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(reporte.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(reportes.this, "Ingresa Un Reporte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                new EnviarDatos(reportes.this).execute();
        }
    });
}
class EnviarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    private Activity contexto;
    EnviarDatos(Activity context){
        this.contexto = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        if(datos()){

        }


        return null;
    }
}

private boolean datos()
{
    cliente = new **DefaultHttpClient()**;
    post = new **HttpPost**("http://192.168.1.254/dbandroid/ws/InsertarUsuario.php");
    lista = new ArrayList<**NameValuePair**>(2);
    lista.**add**(new **BasicNameValuePair**("nombre", nombre.getText().toString().trim()));
    lista.**add**(new **BasicNameValuePair**("reporte", reporte.getText().toString().trim()));

    try{
        post.**setEntity**(new **UrlEncodedFormEntity**(lista));
        cliente.**execute**(post);
        return true;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(**ClientProtocolException** e)
    {
        e.**printStackTrace()**;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}


  }
```

Comment: Cuando ejecutas que te muestra el logcat?

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia pero soy nuevo en esto, que es el logcat?

Comment: Revisa la documentación:  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=es-419 te ayudara a encontrar mas rápido los posibles errores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que no estás importando DefaultHttpClient, si tienes problemas importando la librería este [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio) te puede ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvio de mucha ayuda